# Is there a way to make the boot menu recognize a usb drive (it doesn't at the moment) without entering BIOS?

Tags: ubuntu, boot, bios, usb-flash-drive

After installing Ubuntu on my Fujitsu lifebook (my previous OS was Windows 7 Home Edition) I decided to change my OS again (from a USB stick). However, the only options that the boot menu suggests are: 1. Ubuntu and the diagnostic screen (which, by the way, shows my USB). When I try to access BIOS to change the order settings so that boot menu shows the USB as an option, the laptop beeps and shows "Please wait..." line and then loads the Ubuntu load screen without actually entering BIOS.

From what I've looked up, it seems that Ubuntu messed up something that has to do with BIOS and it needs resetting, which involves physical manipulations with the laptop. And I really don't want to do that because I can accidentally break something.

So, my question is: can I make the boot menu recognize my USB without entering BIOS, and, if that's not possible, are there any other ways to install an OS without boot menu or BIOS? 
[The boot menu not recognizing my USB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsYTv.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone encounters the same problem (it seems to be Fujitsu specific): probably the only way you can make the boot menu recognize your USB is by opening your laptop, removing RAM (it depends on the laptop's model, in some cases you probably don't need to do that) and shortening CL1 and CL2 circuits while the laptop is turned on. Just press two little dots which are signed as CL1 and CL2 with a screwdriver or something metal for about 20 seconds until the boot menu restarts, and then you can proceed with installing an OS from your USB or CD. But bear in mind that you still will not be able to access BIOS. From what I understand, you'll need to install Windows for that.